# Why are many people trying to sell their property in Southern Chennai?

Tags: india, real-estate, selling

I am planning to buy an apartment in **Southern Chennai, India**.
I searched in a leading property website 99acres.com and I am wondering about some results.

I searched all **residential** buildings+land in the area **Chennai - South**.

There are around **~15000** results for **resale** (old property) and just ~**1500** results for **new** apartments/buildings.

Resale vs new property ratio is almost **10:1**.

Please refer to this [link](https://www.99acres.com/search/property/buy/residential-all/chennai-south?search_type=QS&refSection=GNB&search_location=CP32&lstAcn=CP_R&lstAcnId=32&src=CLUSTER&preference=S&selected_tab=1&city=34&res_com=R&property_type=1%2C4%2C2%2C3%2C90%2C5%2C22&isvoicesearch=N&keyword_suggest=chennai%20south%3B&fullSelectedSuggestions=chennai%20south&strEntityMap=W3sidHlwZSI6ImNpdHkifSx7IjEiOlsiY2hlbm5haSBzb3V0aCIsIkNJVFlfMzQsIFBSRUZFUkVOQ0VfUywgUkVTQ09NX1IiXX1d&texttypedtillsuggestion=chennai&refine_results=Y&Refine_Localities=Refine%20Localities&action=%2Fdo%2Fquicksearch%2Fsearch&suggestion=CITY_34%2C%20PREFERENCE_S%2C%20RESCOM_R&searchform=1&price_min=null&price_max=null).

Is it true that many people are trying to sell their property? If so, why are they selling?

This trend is worrying me as a person planning to buy there.

Comment: Maybe it’s the floods.

Comment: That was in 2016, but now people struggling for water.

Comment: What is the total number of housing units in this city? That number is more important than the ratio of existing to new home sales.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chennai has had a run of bad luck: [floods, cyclones, and most recently, an acute and critical water shortage](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-48797399). You really might want to reconsider buying there until the water crisis is resolved.

Comment: Or buy now while the prices are low.

Comment: @RonJohn maybe, but then you are making a bet on climate trends and human responses to them. Buying real estate in a city of several million people without a reliable water supply and no plans on the table to fix the problem seems like a pretty risky investment. Which is presumably why people are selling.